# Machine Learning Math Requirements

Tags: machine-learning, math, open-ai

What area of math do i need for AI and ML? and some recommendations for YouTube math's playlist
I've just started to learn to code in python and i want to go to the path of AI/ML

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of pre-requisites (not-exhaustive, but a good representation)-

- Calculus I and II (For a foundational understanding of the underlying math)
- Linear Algebra (For more intuitive understanding)
- Statistics and Probability (to understand how data works for you ;))

Of course, this goes without saying, you will need a good understanding of a programming language (python in your case) before starting to use the following libraries.

Here are some python based libraries that are way too valuable to us-

(Basic)

- Numpy
- Pandas
- Matplotlib

(Advanced)

- SciPy
- Scikit-learn
- Tensorflow
- Keras
- Pytorch

Please note that the libraries are divided into basic and advanced. You can start with the pre-requisites and basic libraries and then slowly move on to the more advanced ones.

Comment: Where should i start at the math since I've just learned basic math im not really good at it and im following cornell machine learning course?

Comment: It's good that you know you are not good at it. No one is, at the start. Based on your skill level, I will suggest taking a more basic course to start (try udemy if you can) or seeing some fundamentals courses on Coursera. If you feel comfortable with Matlab, Andrew Ng's course on ML on Coursera is highly recommended.

Comment: Before watching the course? What area of math should I learn statistics, calculus, linear algebra? Im really lost

Comment: This is a non-specific answer as the order may vary case by case. For me, based on my understanding, I'd suggest start with linear algebra, move to calculus, and then dive into statistics and probability.